# Query noise level in Android

Tags: android, microphone, noise

I want to develop a small Android app to measure the current noise level (probablyin dB). But I have no idea what to look for in the libs. I don't want to record the noise. Can someone give me a pointer what classes to look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend looking in these classes:

```
android.media.AudioFormat
android.media.AudioManager
android.media.AudioTrack
```

We used them in the [Blinkendroid audio package](http://code.google.com/p/blinkendroid/source/browse/trunk/blinkendroid/src/org/cbase/blinkendroid/audio/?r=96) a short while ago.

Comment: I had a look through those, it seems to me you'd have to record a file, immediately process that file to get the noise level, repeat, which would be extremely inefficient. There's no direct access to the microphone in there...

Comment: Maybe these three classes in the repository might help you there:

http://code.google.com/p/blinkendroid/source/browse/trunk/blinkendroid/src/org/cbase/blinkendroid/audio/?r=96

We've recorded, processed and visualized audio in this project, but dropped it again.

Comment: I was hoping to do it without recording, but I will check.

Comment: In order to do something with the sound you have to record it. You don't have to save it on the device, though.

Comment: Now that I know what to search for, I also found this thread, which also uses recording: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/504e8bb570cc6b08?pli=1

Comment: I think what he meant by "without recording" is that he was hoping he wouldn't have to actually record anything, that there would be a sensor that could be used to detect the dB level around the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shows how we obtained the noise level in the past. Unfortunately the documentation does not tell what unit #getMaxAmplitude() returns.

```
// Start recording but don't store data
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();

// Obtain maximum amplitude since last call of getMaxAmplitude()
while(someCondition) {
    int amplitude = mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
}

// Don't forget to release
mediaRecorder.reset();
mediaRecorder.release();
```