# How to get noise level using the built-in microphone in Android

Tags: android, noise

What I want is to be able to get the current noise level in decibels (dB) on the click of a Button. I have been playing around with the sensors and can get them to work easily but this.. I'm stumped. I've tried a few codes but none work, or helped me understand this.

How can this be achieved?

EDIT:

I use the following code:

```
    private Thread recordingThread;
private int bufferSize = 800;
private short[][] buffers = new short[256][bufferSize];
private int[] averages = new int[256];
private int lastBuffer = 0;

AudioRecord recorder;
boolean recorderStarted = false;

protected void startListenToMicrophone()
{
    if (!recorderStarted)
    {

        recordingThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize * 10);
                recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(bufferSize);
                recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
                    {
                        short[] buffer = buffers[++lastBuffer
                                % buffers.length];
                        recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        long sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i)
                        {
                            sum += Math.abs(buffer[i]);
                        }
                        averages[lastBuffer % buffers.length] = (int) (sum / bufferSize);
                        lastBuffer = lastBuffer % buffers.length;
                        Log.i("dB", ""+averages);
                        tv4.setText("" + averages[1]);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder)
                    {
                    }
                });

                recorder.startRecording();
                short[] buffer = buffers[lastBuffer % buffers.length];
                recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (true)
                {
                    if (isInterrupted())
                    {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        recordingThread.start();

        recorderStarted = true;
    }
}

private void stopListenToMicrophone()
{
    if (recorderStarted)
    {
        if (recordingThread != null && recordingThread.isAlive()
                && !recordingThread.isInterrupted())
        {
            recordingThread.interrupt();
        }
        recorderStarted = false;
    }
}
    }
```

I have two buttons in my app. First one calls startListenToMicrophone and second calls the stop. I don't understand how this works. I got the code from here.

The textview gets a weird and very big value. What I need is the sound level in decibels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query noise level in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567753/query-noise-level-in-android)

Comment: I explored that. The solution provided there didn't work.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to describe in what way it didn't work.

Comment: Details added. Kindly answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Just a passing thought and I may be ver very wrong but, amplitude in dB=20xlog(S1/S2). 
I couldn't find this calculation anywhere in your code. what you need to do is get S1, which will be the current recorded level and get S2 which needs to be the maximum possible value to record. Then calculate the dB value.